# Mock SQLAlchemy database URI with pytest

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest

I have a Flask app that is create via the app factory method:

**appname/__init__.py**

```py
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        from appname.db import db_session

    @app.teardown_appcontext
    def shutdown_session(exception=None):
        db_session.remove()

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(port=5050)
```

The URI for my database is stored in an environment variable and created using standard SQLAlchemy boilerplate:

**appname/db.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import os

engine = create_engine(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI'), echo=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

This setup works fine for developing, but I can't figure out how to set the `DATABASE_URI` variable for pytest. Right now I have to specify it along with the `pytest` command:

```sh
DATABASE_URI='postgresql://me@localhost/appname' pipenv run pytest
```

While this works, I have to imagine there's a better way to predefine the environment for my test suite. What's the best-practices way to set these environment variables?

Comment: Checkout pytest [monkeypatch.setenv](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch.setenv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

**test/conftest.py**

```py
import pytest
from _pytest import monkeypatch
from appname import create_app


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    mp = monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch()
    mp.setenv('DATABASE_URI', 'postgresql://me@localhost/appname')
    app = create_app()
    client = app.test_client()

    yield client
```